# Electron .Net Core . Unable to update database . How to configure sqllite or sqlcompact in Electron

Tags: database, sqlite, asp.net-core, electron, sql-server-ce

I converted a default .net core application and converted it to electron. but the database is not working. what steps should i use to add a local DB.

Application loads, but data is empty

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add Entity Framework as in default net core app and add a DbContext. Then configure the startup class to UseSqlite provider instead of UseSqlServer. It's really simple and it works as expected.
Be sure to mark the database file properties in VS to Copy Always, so you have in the bin folder the updated DB